# Inheritance from scrapy.Item with super() calling: only Python 3.6 raises TypeError : __class__ set to <class MyItem>

Tags: python, scrapy, typeerror, super, python-3.6

Minimal example:

```
import scrapy

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __init__(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's perfectly interpreted by Python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5, **but** Python 3.6.0 raises the `TypeError` exception:

```
TypeError: __class__ set to <class '__main__.MyItem'> defining 'MyItem' as <class '__main__.MyItem'>
```

Same exception is raised by Python 3.6.0, if any other method is overrided in the same manner. Why?

But classes without calling `super()` are interpreted normally by Python 3.6.0:

```
import scrapy

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    pass

class MyItem2(scrapy.Item):
    def new_method(self):
        pass

class MyItem3(scrapy.Item):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

I uses Scrapy 1.3, the [scrapy.Item](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.3/scrapy/item.py) implementation with metaclasses is [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.3/scrapy/item.py).

Comment: Bug discussion: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2509 . Main reason: PEP 487 https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep487

Comment: Bug was fixed: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2509. It will be available in the 1.3.1 release.